# Showing $\sigma_{a}(x) = x^{a}$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ iff $gcd(a,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ and for each integer $a$ let $\sigma_{a}: \mathbb{Z}_{n} \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}, \; \sigma_{a}(x)=x^{a}$. Show that this is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ iff $gcd(a,n)=1$

$\sigma_{a}$ is a homomorphism since $\sigma_{a}(xy) = (xy)^{a} = x^{a}y^{a} = \sigma_{a}(x)\sigma_{a}(y)$

However, I do not immediately see how to show surjectivity/injectivity and how $gcd(a,n)=1$ plays a role in the surjectivity of the function.

Ideas?

Comment: To avoid confusion on what $x^a$ means, I suggest you use $C_n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

As the map is one between finite sets injective, surjective, and bijective are equivalent. Hence, it suffices to investigate if it is injective.

As it is a group homomorphism  injectivity is equivalent to  the kernel is trivial.

Let $g$ be a generating element. Let $y= g^b$ with $0 \le b \le n-1$ be an arbitrary element. Suppose $y^a = e$.

As $y^a = g^{ab}= e$ it follows that $n \mid ab$.

Now, see if you can show that in case the gcd is $1$ this is only possible if $b=0$ and hence $y=e$ while otherwise there is another choice of $b$ too.

Comment: Alternatively, write $au+nv=1$ and then $y=y^1=(y^a)^u (y^n)^v=ee=e$.

Comment: I feel bad saying this, but I unfortunately do not understand your hint. $g$ is a generator $<g>$ and you let $y = g^b$. i.e, $<g^b>$. Suppose $y^a = e$. Then, by corollary of Lagranges Theorem (I think), $g^{ab} = e$. The order of the Cyclic group $n$ divides $ab$ also by Lagrange (I think). Now, I do not understand the ending sentence.

Comment: The group is cyclic, and it thus have some generator $g$. The group $Z_n$ is equal to $\langle g \rangle$. Every element $y \in Z_n$ is thus of the form $g^b$ for some $b$. Then that $y^a = g^{ab}$ is just rules for calculating with exponent. And $y^a= e$ holds by assumption. That $n \mid ab$ is true as the order of $g$ is $n$. This is not  Lagrange's theorem but just that $g$ is a generator of a cyclic group of order $n$.  To continue: if $n \mid ab$  and  $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and  then $n \mid b$ and $b=0$ as there is no other multiple of $n$ in the range of posible values of $b$.

Comment: If the gcd is not $1$ take $b = n/\gcd(n,a)$ to get a non trivial element of the kernel.